# Нельзя добавить файл в SVN в Intellij idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, macos, svn, контроль-версий

Есть svn сервер в интернете. Открыл idea, сделал checkout. Коммитить и апдейтиться можно, однако, новые файлы никак не получается добавить в VCS через IDE.
        [image: Неактивное меню]
        [image: Настройки SVN в IDEA]
        [image: Нельзя добавить в VCS]
        [image: Настройки workspace]
        [image: Local changes]

Comment: Какие сообщения выводятся на консоль?

Comment: Извините, не могу её найти. Если вы имели ввиду это https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/version-control-tool-window-console-tab.html, то как ни странно, такой вкладки у меня нет.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что вся папка src игнорировалась на уровне самого svn и поэтому нельзя было добавить файл в VCS.